# NSData to NSString conversion failing

Tags: java, ios, nsstring, converters, nsdata

I have an encrypted String that is returned by a Java web service to my iOS app.  I am able to decrypt it to a NSData object on the iOS side, but when I try to convert it to a NSString I always get a null value returned.  I have tried the following commands:

```
NSString *msg1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *msg2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[messageData bytes]];
NSString *msg3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *msg4 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[messageData bytes]];
```

The decrypted message should say "This is test message:".  The only one of these commands that comes anywhere close is msg3, but even that garbles the output, which looks like "This is test mes¯5[Lqë÷£©ìÇt1"

Can anyone explain to me why this conversion is failing?

Comment: if you log each of those, how does your output change?  without knowing specifically what your service returns it's difficult to help you out.

Comment: What's the encoding on the web service side?

Comment: Provide a NSLog of the data, many of us can figure out a log by looking at the hex display. Perhaps it is base64 encoded.

Comment: Have you tried this encoding : NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: I think it might be a problem with encoding, make sure server side and iPhone side using the same encoding